# Different favicon for chat window/tab

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat

When I have opened (and pinned in Chrome) SO website and SO chat tabs both of them have the same favicon and they are not visually distinguishable.

[image]

Is it possible to have a different favicon for chat window/tab? For example with small bubble (or something like that) in addition to SO logo to indicate that this tab belongs to chat.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Part of the problem there is that this would involve, what, 100 more icons? So to do it in a pragmatic way, you'd probably want to overlay with something (maybe something like a mouth, or text lines, or a speech bubble or something); but that may or may not look "right"...

Don't get me wrong... it could probably be done; but it would need some consideration.

Comment: It can be done programmatically using `canvas` - see the favicon notifier script we have: http://rchern.github.com/StackExchangeScripts/

Comment: @Yi - oh, that's the *easy* bit; making sure it looks right on each icon, though... and then there's 6 levels of committe and pre-meeting-meetings to decide the colour and shape of the glyph on a per-day basis...

Comment: Has SE morphed into MS? What's the Norwegian Localization Committee's finding on this? Seriously, though, add me to the list of people who came here to ask for this feature. Alternatively, It'd be useful to prepend "Chat" to the title that comes up in the browser tab. Anything you can do to disambiguate between chat and main would be great.

Comment: @MarcGravell A committee should consist of no more than 3 members, two of whom are absent.

Comment: @IsaacMoses At least now (dunno if it's recent), the title already specifies Chat *[ edit] this is probably only for single-user chats, not general ones, so nvm [/edit]*, but in any case, the question was about the icon being a problem _because the title is hidden_ in such cases. I'm surprised this still hasn't been resolved (cf the new thread asking the same thing).

Answer (score 19):

Came here to ask the same thing after just discovering pinned tabs in Chrome.  At the moment, I've taken @YiJiang's idea to use the `<canvas>` element to add a permanent bubble to the favicon, so it looks like this:

[image: favicon with speech bubble]

It's not perfect — I'm no artist, but it helps me distinguish between the windows until we get an official solution.  I had an idea that the indicator could change colour based on the number of unread chat messages à la comment vote count.  As for @ notifications, it could blink (cos everyone loves images that blink) and/or display a number for the amount of direct notifications.

Answer (score 4):

Posting here since I was about to create the exact same question: this is highly wanted! Perhaps a subte little "c" on top of the favicon, or some kind of chat bubble.

Comment: "c" doesn't localize.

Answer (score 2):

Can I suggest that very specifically for 'The Comms Room' we add a number eight rotated 90 degrees to the icon as an indicator of it being that particular room - it would be highly representative of its content.