# Can we differentiate the sub-domains (blog/chat/etc) favicons to help with tab organization?

Tags: feature-request, favicon, subdomains

Like many people I keep lots of tabs open at once. It would be nice if the favicon was slightly different for and hinted at each of the subdomain for things like blog and chat, so the tabs can be found easily.

Comment: Hard to add too much detail to a 16x16 pixel icon... And I'd prefer that they remain easily distinguishable from my *other* pages, more so than I would prefer they be easily distinguishable from each other. But if we can work some absolute magic here in the realm of icon design, well, I could definitely support that.

Comment: Looks like somone responded to a similar feature-request in the past with this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85146/different-favicon-for-chat-window-tab/95384#95384 which looks like it could work