# Change the browser tab title on chat pages to chat.sitename or chat.room name

Tags: feature-request, chat

When I have the main site open in one tab and the general discussion for the same site open in another. I can't tell them apart from the browser tab title.

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot, I can't tell the chat from the main site. Changing the title for the chat tab would be helpful. I see this feature request for [Different favicon for chat window/tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85146/132547) and that might work too.

Answer (score 6):

The default name for a site's chat room is "$sitename Chat", leading to ambiguity unless you have *very* few (or wide) browser tabs, but there's no reason you need to keep that name.  Many sites rename their chat rooms.  Here are a couple tabs from my browser; even without the "(1*)" telling me that somebody wants my attention in that room, I'd be able to tell which is the site and which is the chat room by the names:

[image: Mi Yodeya and its chat room]